Vite build issue, appears to be an out-of-order bundle
This is a strange one, and I'm hoping someone can at least point us in the right direction.
We're converting a pretty large, fairly legacy ejected CRA app to vite. We've come pretty far, have it building, 99% functional in dev mode, and builds without errors.
However, if we run the build, we get this error immediately with a blank white screen:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'index$3' before initialization
    at assets/index-Cb4xHw7-.js (dispatch-handler.js:16:1)
    at __require (index-Cb4xHw7-.js:34:50)
    at index.tsx:44:1

If we follow that stacktrace, the file is just a seemingly random redux file. The error doesn't seem to be related to redux directly, although I'm open to being proven wrong.
As this is a migration from Webpack, it currently builds all of the js into one large file (about 11mb before gzip). We know, but chunking is (hopefully) an effort for another day). Webpack builds the same way, into one large chunk, and works fine.
If we open that large file in the inspector, you can clearly see the function it's referencing hundreds of lines below, so the problem is clear, just not the why.
This same issue occurs when building with or without sourcemap, with or without minify.
Now, here's the fun part: if I put a breakpoint right before the problem line, reload the app, let it sit for 20-30 seconds (I haven't timed out the exact minimum), then continue execution...it works.
So, my theory is that the large file is taking too long to load and process, so the referenced value doesn't have time to initialize but the extra few seconds at the breakpoint gives it time to catch up.
What I don't have is enough vite / rollup knowledge to fix either the bundle order or the loading time.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more information if there's a specific configuration value or piece of info that might help. We've been banging our heads against the wall on this for a couple days.

Have you made sure the Redux lib is updated? It could just be a bug that's been fixed in a newer version

redux@^4.2.1 and react-redux@^7.2.9; they've also been updated as part of this effort, but we're not using RTK
